# Treeset Internally process Strings

Tags: java, treeset

I have the following code but I am unable to understand the output as how TreeSet is producing the following output. How does TreeSet store Objects internally?

```
import java.util.*;

class TreeSetDemo{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        TreeSet<String> treeset = new TreeSet<String>(); 

        treeset.add("Geeks");
        treeset.add("for");
        treeset.add("GeeksforGeeks");
        treeset.add("a");
        treeset.add("d");
        treeset.add("c");
        treeset.add("b");

        for(String temp:treeset)
            System.out.printf(temp+ " ");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Geeks GeeksforGeeks a b c d for
```

Comment: `TreeSet` is a sorted set, so the iterator iterates in sorted sequence. Please explain what you did expect.

Answer (score 1):

> i am unable to understand the output as how treeset is producing the following output . can some explain me how TreeSet store Objects internally.

According to [its docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), `TreeSet` stores its elements in a `TreeMap` (as the keys).  For its part, [`TreeMap` stores its elements in a red-black tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is the basis for both classes' names.  In case you are not aware, a red-black tree is a form of binary search tree.

As for the output, there are two main things to understand:

1. `TreeSet` is a *sorted* set.  If you initialize one with a `Comparator` then that defines the sort order. Otherwise, as in your case, it uses the natural order of the elements.  The set's iterators return elements in sorted order.
2. [Class `String`'s natural order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) is lexicographic, based on the numeric values of the `char` elements of each `String`.

You did not explain how the output you obtained differs from what you expected, but I suppose it must have to do with the order of the strings.  Perhaps you expected them to be iterated in the same order in which you added them to the set, but I have already covered why that would not have been a reasonable expectation.

Or perhaps you were surprised that capital 'G' sorts before all lowercase letters, including, for example, lowercase 'a'.  The numeric values of Java `char`s represent a UTF-16 encoding of Unicode, which is consistent with ASCII for code points 0 - 127.  There are numerous ASCII code charts available on the web, and Unicode charts as well.  Any of these will tell you that the Unicode code point for 'G' is 71 (decimal) and that for 'a' is 97, so indeed (sub)strings beginning with 'G' do sort before those beginning with 'a' in the natural order of `java.lang.String`s.